# jQuery data retrieve from div

Tags: jquery

```
<div align="left" style="margin-bottom:3px;"> 
    <b>ID:</b>
    37749
    <b>Active on:</b>
    03/28/2012
</div>
```

this is my content, how to retrieve numbers. use Jquery

Comment: What do you mean numbers? Do you mean the value of `ID` field `37749`?

Comment: yes, i want to retrieve both ID and date in separate variables

Comment: Retrieving values from plain text is not a straightforward job. It would be better if you change your `html` structure to something like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/Yv2g7/) so that it would be easier to extract the required information.

Comment: it's not my content. this is for public website content and dynamic one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var content=$('div').innerHTML();
var arr=content.split("</b>");
var ID=arr[1].split("<b>")[0];
var date=arr[3];
```

Answer (score 2):

You *should* add some extra HTML.

```
<div align="left" style="margin-bottom:3px;"> 
    <b>ID:</b>
    <span id="id">37749</span>
    <b>Active on:</b>
    <span id="active-on">03/28/2012</span>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
var theID = $('#id').text(),
    activeOn = $('#active-on').text();
});
```

Comment: What? That didn't make sense.

Comment: it's not my contents, public content

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div').contents().map(function() {
    if (this.nodeType == 3 && this.nodeValue.replace(/\s/g, '').length !== 0) {
        return this.nodeValue.replace(/\s/g, '');
    }
}).toArray();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FFaxE/)**